# How to save an Array in UserDefault

Tags: arrays, nsuserdefaults, swift4, xcode9, tabbarcontroller

I'm using a UITabBarController to create a contact list, but when I'm trying to save the array to load the data when I restart the app is giving me problems where the data isn't displayed. I'm using UserDefaults to save the data and the restore when the app is restarted.

In this code I sent data from a textfield to the array named list.

```
import UIKit

class NewContactoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    if (input.text != "") {

        list.append(input.text!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(list, forKey: "SavedValue")
        input.text = ""
    }
}
}
```

In this code I'm printing the data in a table, and trying to save it with user defaults.

```
import UIKit

var list = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedValue") as? String {
        return (x.count)
    }
    return (0)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "SavedValue") as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = [x[indexPath.row]]
    }
    return(cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
}
```

Comment: How you declare list array in NewContactoViewController? and explain more that how you communicate ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving an **array of strings** but you are reading a **single string** (or even a dictionary) which obviously cannot work. There is a dedicated method `stringArray(forKey` to read a string array.

Apart from the issue never read from `UserDefaults` to populate the data source in the table view data source and delegate methods, do it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` for example

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let savedArray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "SavedValue") {
        list = savedArray
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Put the data source array **in** the view controller. A global variable as data source is very bad programming habit.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var list = [String]()
    ...
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return the number of items in `list` and `return` is not a function, there are no parentheses

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}
```

Same in `cellForRow`. Get the item from `list` and use reusable cells and again, `return` is not a function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Note :

Consider that `UserDefaults` is the wrong place to share data between view controllers. Use segues, callbacks or protocol / delegate.

Comment: Thanks it help me a lot, the reason why I declare the array as a global variable it was to access it from the other controller for the tab controller, didn't knew it was a bad habit.